# Why PHP session is deleted on page reload?

Tags: php, session-variables

So I've this problem that, when I'm on the page not doing anything for some time, after I reload the page `$_SESSION` is cleared. I checked the code and it does not have any `unset()` functions or anything else what could clear the `$_SESSION` variable.
Any ideas why is it happening?

**Edit:** In case if I want to make the session live till the browser is closed what should I do? I don't understand it as the `gc` checks if session is expired on `session_start`, but I can't modify the session data before calling `session_start`, so modifying the session data after calling `session_start` would result in expired session anyway?

I've the `session.cookie_lifetime` set to 0 by default, `session.gc_maxlifetime`, `session.gc_divisor`, `session.gc_probability` are set to their default values too.

Comment: What value is *session.gc\_maxlifetime* and did you *understand* [my post on how PHP’s session expiration model works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960)?

Comment: @Gumbo, *session.gc_maxlifetime* is set to default 1440. I think I did, yes. I've *session.gc_probability* and *session.gc_divisor* set those to default values too.

Comment: @Richards: And this vague idle time aren’t these 1440 seconds? Remember that PHP’s default garbage collector calculates the age based on the session file’s modification time.

Comment: @Gumbo, but my question is: how to reset the garbage collector timer for the session so it doesn't erase the session? I'm not understanding it cause, the garbage collector does it's job when the *session_start()* is called, but I can't modify the session data before calling the *session_start()*.

Comment: @Richards: You can’t reset it because there is no timer. It’s the age of the session data (i.e. the time of its last modification) that constitutes in combination with the *session.gc\_maxlifetime* value whether a session is expired. The garbage collector is just the routine that deletes such sessions. And when that happens the session *is* already expired.

Comment: @Gumbo, so to fix this problem I just have to increase the session.gc_maxlifetime to bigger one?

Comment: @Gumbo, what would be safe lifetime? I mean not to overload stuff and so on? What do you have it set to?

Comment: @Richards: That depends on the purpose of your session. So what do you need it for and what would be the consequences of a premature expiry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you put de `session_start()` at the beginning of every page?

Comment: Yes, on each and everypage. No session_destory() used.

Comment: the session_start() problem is very common. I'm looking documentation about the session time out.

Comment: http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/  Can you check it out?

Comment: It showed: string(4) "1440" after printing the lifetime thing out. Is it good?

Comment: that means 1440/60 = 24 minutes os session